# How do I install OS X Yosemite on an unsupported MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have downloaded and made a bootable USB of Yosemite but once I boot holding the option key and attempt to install I get an error stating that Yosemite is already installed on my computer. I'm running Snow Leopard and I made my bootable USB using Diskmaker X.

Comment: diskmaker is not the way to do it

Comment: Describe "unsupported MacBook". What MacBook model are you trying to install Yosemite on that would make it unsupported? Understand well that anything with a 32-bit EFI is simply not going to happen, period.

Answer (score 1):

You should use following to make a bootable Yosemite USB.

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app —nointeraction
```

Just replace the Untitled with name of the USB drive